# How to see comments in history view of Visual SourceSafe?

Tags: version-control, versioning, visual-sourcesafe

While viewing the history of a file in Visual SourceSafe, I see the following columns:

- Version
- User
- Date
- Action

I'm more interested in the comments, I filled in while checking out and in.
I know I can get this information, using the history report preview, but would it be possible adding this as a column in the basic history view?

Comment: Honestly, the final release for this product was 15 years ago. Not much interest in it now. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm afraid nobody knows the answer, OP. The basic problem seems to be that you're having trouble with a program so old its final version was released before Windows Vista came out. I don't know your use case, but I suspect most people are using a more modern (And therefore well-known) program.